# Generate pdf on the fly and email with webmatrix

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix-2

I have a web application which at the moment generates certificates using a template. Since I original wrote it in php, I used the str_replace built in function to replace values in my template with values from the query.

Now I have changed to asp.net web pages and my aim is to generate certificates in pdf and mail them.

I am using iTextSharp and  webmatrix.

Below is part of my code :

```
 var sql = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, Country, Phone FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'ALFKI'";
var data = db.Query(sql);

  foreach(var item in data){ var companyname = item.CompanyName;}

PdfPCell certify1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("companyname"));
certify1.Colspan = 2;
certify1.Border = 0;
certify1.PaddingTop = 40f;
certify1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(certify1);
```

From this code I am trying to show the data from database table. The code above is not working. I am trying to grab the query values and have then in certify1 cell. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Comment: @Mike-Brind  I have added code and interested in showing values from query. The  query returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sql = "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Address, City, Country, Phone FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = 'ALFKI'";
var data = db.Query(sql);

foreach(var item in data){ 
    var companyname = item.CompanyName;
    PdfPCell certify1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(companyname));
    certify1.Colspan = 2;
    certify1.Border = 0;
    certify1.PaddingTop = 40f;
    certify1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
    table.AddCell(certify1);
}
```