# Add image to cell - iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add an image to a pdf cell and I get an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to
>   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell'

in line:

```
content.AddCell(myImage);
```

Here's my code:

```
PdfPTable content = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 500f });
content.AddCell(myImage);
document.Add(content);
```

`myImage` variable is of the Image type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing the API you probably need to create a cell and put the image there and then use `content.AddCell(yourCreatedCell);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't just add an image, you need to create the cell first and add the image to the cell:
http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html#PdfPCell(com.itextpdf.text.Image)

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(myImage);
content.AddCell(cell);
```

You also cannot use the System.Drawing.Image class, iTextSharp has it's own class of Image:
http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html

It needs a URL passed to the constructor to the image location.

So:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image myImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("Image location");
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(myImage);
content.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Now I got an error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'iTextSharp.text.Phrase'

Comment: Apoliges, see details above, you need to use iTextSharps own Image function found here:
http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html

Answer (score 2):

You should create a cell first, then add the image to that cell and finally add the cell the the table.

```
var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/logo.jpg");
var imageCell = new PdfPCell(image);
content.AddCell(imageCell);
```

See answer on this post: [How to add an image to a table cell in iTextSharp using webmatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589044/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-table-cell-in-itextsharp-using-webmatrix)